# Sum Of Common Prime Divisors Of 2 Numbers

Tags: c, methods, primes

I'm having a problem to find/to come up with a solution to this manner.
I was asked to write down a method that receives two integer numbers and returns the sum of the common and prime divisors of those numbers. For example :

I have 2 numbers :
A=48 and B=60

48=2*2*2*2*3
60=2*2*3*5

2,2,3 are the common prime divisors of those two numbers so therefor 2+2+3=7
the method will return 7.

I made a primitive code :

```
    int n=48,k=60;
    int i=2;

    while(n!=1)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
            n/=i;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;        
        }
    }

    i=2;
    System.out.println();

    while(k!=1)
    {
        if(k%i==0)
        {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
            k/=i;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;        
        }
    }
```

How shall I combine the 2 loops to make it calculate simultaneously?

Comment: Ya give us some pseudo code, I think the modulus % operator could be useful. Do you at least know how to at least write the function declaration with the integer attributes?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I'm really sorry for all the errors that might come. This is the first time that I'm asking a question here.
The thing is that I have received this question during an interview for a job. And had google by my side for assistance.
I didn't manage to find any start point.

Comment: That always amazes me (yes, that was irony)... shows us some google queries you've tried.

Comment: find the [Greatest Common Divisor](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Recursive_Euclid_algorithm),  [Prime factorize](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Prime_decomposition#Lua) it, Add up the factors and report sum. You have to lookup standard C code all these steps, and for [Primality Test](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Primality_by_trial_division#C). All the best.

Comment: Compute the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm), [factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms) the result, add up the factors. To compute factors, you first need to find the [primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Testing_primality_and_integer_factorization).

Comment: "common prime factors of 2 numbers", "prime divisors", "gcd factors" that's what I've tried in google. It always got to the GCD function and that isn't what I need.

Comment: see how to find out the gcd of two numbers in google, as @MarkedOne also said, it is so easy, give it a try please

Comment: @ MarkedOne: that is mostly what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you pseudocode, and leave it to you to translate to C. First, Euclid's algorithm to find the greatest common divisor of two numbers:

```
function gcd(a, b)
    if b == 0
        return a
    return gcd(b, a % b)
```

For instance, `gcd(48, 60) = 12`. Next, a simple function that factors integers by trial division:

```
function factors(n)
    f, fs := 2, []
    while f * f <= n
        while n % f == 0
            fs.append(f)
            n := n / f
        f := f + 1
    if n > 1
        fs.append(f)
    return fs
```

For instance, `factors(12) = [2, 2, 3]`. Then just put them together:

```
function sum-of-common-factors(x, y)
    return sum(factors(gcd(x, y)))
```

There are better ways to factor larger integers, but that's probably sufficient for a job interview.